# BIOS does not detect Linux drive after power outage

Tags: linux, bios

On my desktop I have 2 drives, Linux and windows, I barely use windows.
The power went down in my town for 3 secs and now my bios does not find the Linux drive.
It is not toasted.

Comment: `It is not toasted.` how do you know? it certainly seems to be given BIOS can't detect it

Comment: Because I can access the drive from my other pc

Comment: Maybe the motherboard connection or cable is fried. Can you connect the Linux drive in place of the Windows drive and see if it works?

Comment: You should acquire more info by specific tests and provide them here. (1) Did you test the disk with different cables (power/data) board-connector? (2) Did you test different board connectors? (3) Does another disk show up at the same connectors+cables? (4) Can you exchange the power unit and test? — Note that the power unit might have a defect and some of the provided voltages or current might be out of specs.

Comment: Being able to see the drive in another computer is information that should be in the question itself. Good questions are more likely to get better answers, so using the EDIT button is strongly encouraged.